# How to read multiple value with checkboxes and autosum?

Tags: javascript, php

I solve the autosum but the problem is when I choose 1 or 2 item or product it will record all the product. What should I do?

I expected to autosum the total amount with item name or list I chose.

HTML/PHP

```
<input type="hidden" class="test" name="request_test[]" onclick="autoSum(this);" i="" value="CBC">
<input type="checkbox" class="test" onclick="autoSum(this);" i="" value="50" data-price="50" >

<input type="hidden" class="test" name="request_test[]" onclick="autoSum(this);" i="" value="FBS">
<input type="checkbox" class="test" onclick="autoSum(this);" i="" value="200">
```

JavaScript

```
var total=0;
function autoSum(elem) {
 
    if (elem.checked == true) { 
        total += Number(elem.value); 
    }else{
        total -=Number(elem.value);
    }
 
    document.getElementById('amount').value = total.toFixed(0);
}
```

Comment: You have an onclick event attribute on a hidden input. You cannot click a hidden input.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Give a proper explanation of what you are actually trying to do there first of all. _"it will record all the product"_ - what does that mean, who is "recording" and where? _"when I choose 1 or 2 item or product"_ - so there's items _and_ products? What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

You can study this example

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" class="test" onClick="autoSum(this);" i="" value="50" data-price="50" >

  <input type="checkbox" class="test" onClick="autoSum(this);" i="" value="200">
  
  <p id="amount">0</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function autoSum(elem) {
  
  var total=0;
  var allCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
  
  allCheckBoxes.forEach(function(elem) {
    
    if (elem.checked === true) {
       total += Number(elem.value);
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = total;
}
```

demo link here https://jsbin.com/nedadawume/edit?html,js,console,output